# WebNative Portal Xinet - Grab image

Tags: php, html, portal

I am trying to grab an image on my WebNative Xinet portal. When i use the method i am using right now: I get an image back, but i also get all the HTML with it to display the image. This is what i am using to grab the image right now:

```
GETIMAGE.php?type=small&path=/Images/myimage.png
```

This is kind of working. The issue with this is that it returns a complete HTML document with the image tags in it displaying the image.

How is it possible to get the raw image back with no HTML included? My main objective is to grab the image and encode it to base64 to be displayed in an e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

That request should absolutely be giving you an HTTP response with an image payload.

I'm assuming you're using cURL to speak with Portal.  Did you authenticate with server before making the GETIMAGE.php request?  If so, are you including the session ID cookie in your GETIMAGE.php request?

EDIT: I saw your other post and it looks exactly like the auto-generated code Chrome shows in its DOM inspector.  Are you *sure* you're getting HTML from that URL?  I'm staring at the source and I can't find anywhere where it emits HTML.